the length of time vs the duration


Thirty-two hours was the length of time General Motor spent on average to manufacture a vehicle in 1998.
Thirty-two hours was the duration General Motor spent on average to manufacture a vehicle in 1998. 
Thirty-two hours was what General Motor spent on average to manufacture a vehicle in 1998.


Which version is natural here? I can't really differentiate between the duration and the length of time.

I assume you are intending to compare "32 hours" with something else, otherwise it would be more natural to make "General Motors" the subject (also you, or the graphic, has the name of the car company wrong.  "Motors" is plural.

Durations are not "spent" in the sense you are using the verb here.  Units of time are spent.  You could say "He spent the duration in solitary confinement" but that is a different sense of "spent".  Why are you wishing to avoid "GM spent 32 hours on average to manufacture a vehicle" ?

What you want is "amount of time" not "length".  Length refers to the time as a contiguous span, when what is needed here is a quantity.

Of the three, the third is the most natural, but none is very good. What is the 32 hours supposed to measure - the total man-hours, the time it took to go through the production line, the amount of time spent by the one guy who made it, the time for each individual procedure added together, the number of hours the factory was open divided by the number of cars made, or what? Did the whole factory make one car then stop and make the next car?

I used "thirty-two hours" as the subject because I felt like it should be used when the following phrase was "...., with a subsequent decline to 22 hours after seven years".

The most natural phrasing for the context is #4...

Thirty-two hours was how long General Motors...
...spent on average manufacturing... (valid, but imho "clunky")
...took on average to manufacture...
...a vehicle in 1998.

Comments to the question notwithstanding, there's nothing remotely unusual about using metaphoric length for a total amount of time that's comprised of many shorter (possibly contiguous and/or overlapping) segments contributed by different workers.

Yes, how long is the most idiomatic here.

I can't downvote TimR's comment: "Length refers to the time as a contiguous span, when what is needed here is a quantity", but I see no truth in it. As you and I both agree, how long is the most idiomatic here. But there wouldn't be anything wrong with Thirty-two hours was the amount of time General Motors took on average to manufacture a vehicle in 1998. And the length of time is at least "syntactically valid" - it's just stylistically clumsy by comparison.

Sure, it could also be length of time, right? But that is long. Better is shorter.  I still think how long is best.

Yes, like I said, it seems we both agree there are various options (but as is so often the case, "shorter is better"). My point was it wouldn't be good for learners to think there are any real semantic issues here. An amount of time can be the total of various contiguous and/or overlapping segments OR a single duration from a start time until an end time. Metaphoric length of time / how long works fine for both referents.
